Remove notice only for Composite Products in Woocommerce
I would like to only get a 'Product is removed' for the product type 'Composite Product'. Currently, when I would remove a composite product in WooCommerce, it will display a notice for all child products that are removed in the cart. The only notice I would like to keep, is from the composite product itself.
So just 1 notice instead of i.e. 10 notices. See picture below:

The thing is that the composite product contains either product bundles, or single products. So every other product type should be excluded from showing the notice. It properly works with adding, but only not with removing.
To clarify, I am using a Divi theme but no Divi editing for the basket and cart page, because then it doesn't work at all. I have access to the php files if necessary.
And also I hope someone can help me with the red marked issue.

Fixed the red box, because of SEO plugin that didn't work properly
